# What are ideogram escape codes used for in ANSI-compatible terminals

Tags: terminal, ansi-escape, terminal-emulator

ANSI X3.64[1] and ECMA-48[2] video terminal escape codes define a set of parameters for Select Graphic Rendition that have to do with ideograms. Specifically:

```
60 ideogram underline or right side line
61 ideogram double underline or double line on the right side
62 ideogram overline or left side line
63 ideogram double overline or double line on the left side
64 ideogram stress marking
65 cancels the effect of the rendition aspects established by parameter values 60 to 64
```

Wikipedia lists these codes as "rarely supported" but doesn't go into any detail, and from what I can tell, ECMA-48 is very sparse about the intention behind escape codes.

I'm trying to figure out what these escape codes were intended for, what an implementation for them would look like, and if any video terminals ever actually implemented this.

Any clues would be greatly appreciated!

1. I've actually only been able to find copies of ECMA-48, so please correct me if I'm making a wrong assumption about X3.64.
2. https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-048.pdf
3. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#SGR_(Select_Graphic_Rendition)_parameters ([permalink](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=ANSI_escape_code&oldid=883006508#SGR_(Select_Graphic_Rendition)_parameters))

Comment: Looks like an attempt to expand support for East Asian symbols that didn't pan out.  The clues are stress and vertical lines.  Wikipedia mentions that most are now considered logograms rather than ideograms.  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideogram

Comment: I have no idea. But in the absence of documentation, this looks like an attempt to create a karyogram language in the console. A second hypothesis would be an early attempt to support logogram languages, but I don't know why such a language would need double underline markup.